# Does a Windows 8.1 product key work on Windows 7?

Tags: installation, windows-installation

I currently have a system that is shipped preinstalled with genuine Windows 8.1. I would like a fresh install of Windows 7 instead. Would it be possible to use the key that is contained in this OS to be applied to install Windows 7?

Comment: Why would a Windows 8.1 product activate or install Windows 7? If you want Windows 7 you should go purchase a Windows 7 license or downgrade your license to Windows 7 provided its Windows 8.1 Professional.  Contact your system OEM for what you options are, they are the sole party, responsible for providing your downgrade rights to Windows 7.

Comment: To be direct, @Ramhound. I would like to erase the disk with a full install of Linux and run Windows 7 in a VM. I wouldn't want to waste the OS that is purchased along with the system, so that's is why asked for this alternative.

Comment: If you downgrade OS to Windows 7 you can't run Windows 8.1 using that license.  What you want to do requires a separate Windows 7 license.

Comment: You cannot use an Windows OEM key with a VM installation of Windows, it will not validate even if the key if for that machine. In order to have a valid copy of Windows in a VM you must have a full retail license key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not only is a product key specific to the whole version, its also specific to the sub version.

This means, a Windows 8.1 Professional key will not work on a Windows 8.1 Home or Enterprise version. Nor will it work with windows 7, Vista or any other version, with the exception of Windows 10, which, until end of juli 2016 will accept windows 7 and 8 keys and convert them to windows 10 installation id's.

With that key, you can only install windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

No. The product key will be valid for Windows 8 (and at time of writing, Windows 10), of the corresponding edition you have installed only. The product key will not entitle you to use any other product.